# how long will smbtree takes to find a computer on networks?

Tags: samba, smb

Hi after googling for last one week on smbtree.i am curios to know how much time does smbtree takes best and the worst case.currently on my home network it takes roughly 40-50 sec.

Every time i do smbtree on my linux terminal it takes different times(same network) as below

```
1 test it tooks 40.01 sec
2 test it took  45.34 sec
3 test it took  41.00sec
```

why the time very though if i try on my home network(same network).
**Is there any way to find the exact time before i do smbtree so that i can ask  my user to relax till that time ?**

Answer (score 1):

You can't know future times.

Smbtree Times depending on many factors such as

1.How larger your network is
2.No of computer on the network
3.Any many more factor

smb itself has many bugs.